# Fixed column using TableView library

Tags: android, tableview

I am using *evrencoskun* TableView library in my project. https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView

What I want to do is to fix the last column of the table when scolling horizontal, so that the column will be visible at all times. After some research I wasn't able to find anything that can help me accomplish that.

Does anyone know a workaround which can help me do that? I would really apreciate it since I'm really out of ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So this is possible using evrencoskun TableView BUT it requires changes to the library.

Below is a quick hack of the library with the corner View now top right and Row headers on the Right.

If that is what you wanted then I suggest you add a feature request in GitHub to make this an option or if you are willing to build the library yourself then I can update the answer with details of the quick hack.

[image]

**Update**

Code to do this now merged to main Project.
https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView/pull/357

Comment: Man library now can fix the row headers to the right, just need it to be released.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I recommend you to use RecyclerView and add header decoration
Here is an article with sample code https://medium.com/@eXa/simple-header-view-on-recyclerview-for-android-364a4fd319fe